# DataError: No numeric types to aggregate when merging two dataframes with same index

Tags: pandas

I want to find the rows in `meth450_clin_kipan` and `meth_450_10k_kipan` dataframes with the same index values. If the index values match, I want to retrieve the `admin.disease_code` column from the `meth450_clin_kipan` and merge it together with the `meth_450_10k_kipan` dataframe, creating a new dataframe `meth_sub`.

```
# Add tumor subtype info to methylation df
# If TCGA ID in clinical df matches the TCGA ID in methylation df, retrieve the "admin.disease_code" column value from the clinical df
meth_sub = pd.concat([meth450_clin_kipan, meth_450_10k_kipan], 1).dropna().mean(axis=1, level=0)
meth_sub
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DataError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-195091af1790> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 # Add tumor subtype info to methylation df
      2 # If TCGA ID in clinical df matches the TCGA ID in methylation df, retrieve the "admin.disease_code" column value from the clinical df
----> 3 meth_sub = pd.concat([meth450_clin_kipan, meth_450_10k_kipan], 1).dropna().mean(axis=1, level=0)
      4 meth_sub

/shared-libs/python3.9/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in mean(self, axis, skipna, level, numeric_only, **kwargs)
  11116         )
  11117         def mean(self, axis=None, skipna=None, level=None, numeric_only=None, **kwargs):
> 11118             return NDFrame.mean(self, axis, skipna, level, numeric_only, **kwargs)
  11119 
  11120         # pandas\core\generic.py:10924: error: Cannot assign to a method

/shared-libs/python3.9/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in mean(self, axis, skipna, level, numeric_only, **kwargs)
  10724 
  10725     def mean(self, axis=None, skipna=None, level=None, numeric_only=None, **kwargs):
> 10726         return self._stat_function(
  10727             "mean", nanops.nanmean, axis, skipna, level, numeric_only, **kwargs
  10728         )

/shared-libs/python3.9/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _stat_function(self, name, func, axis, skipna, level, numeric_only, **kwargs)
  10708             axis = self._stat_axis_number
  10709         if level is not None:
> 10710             return self._agg_by_level(name, axis=axis, level=level, skipna=skipna)
  10711         return self._reduce(
  10712             func, name=name, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, numeric_only=numeric_only

/shared-libs/python3.9/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _agg_by_level(self, name, axis, level, skipna, **kwargs)
  10557         grouped = self.groupby(level=level, axis=axis, sort=False)
  10558         if hasattr(grouped, name) and skipna:
> 10559             return getattr(grouped, name)(**kwargs)
  10560         axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
  10561         method = getattr(type(self), name)

/shared-libs/python3.9/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in mean(self, numeric_only)
   1494         Name: B, dtype: float64
   1495         """
-> 1496         return self._cython_agg_general(
   1497             "mean",
   1498             alt=lambda x, axis: Series(x).mean(numeric_only=numeric_only),

/shared-libs/python3.9/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in _cython_agg_general(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
   1013         self, how: str, alt=None, numeric_only: bool = True, min_count: int = -1
   1014     ) -> DataFrame:
-> 1015         agg_mgr = self._cython_agg_blocks(
   1016             how, alt=alt, numeric_only=numeric_only, min_count=min_count
   1017         )

/shared-libs/python3.9/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py in _cython_agg_blocks(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
   1119 
   1120         if not len(new_mgr):
-> 1121             raise DataError("No numeric types to aggregate")
   1122 
   1123         return new_mgr

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

`meth450_clin_kipan`:

```
meth450_clin_kipan.iloc[0:3,0:3].to_dict()

{'admin.disease_code': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': 'kirp',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': 'kirp',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': 'kirp'},
 'days_to_death': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': nan,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': nan,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': nan},
 'vital_status': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': 'alive',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': 'alive',
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': 'alive'}}
```

`meth_450_10k_kipan`:

```
meth_450_10k_kipan.iloc[0:3,0:3].to_dict()

    {'cg00000029': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': 0.461440642939772,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': 0.595894468074615,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': 0.481304782143526},
 'cg00000165': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': 0.143910373119058,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': 0.0807243779293262,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': 0.437447195378987},
 'cg00000236': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A': 0.847164847154162,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A': 0.867305510246114,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A': 0.898927359292032}}
```

Expected output `meth_sub`:

|  | cg00000029 | cg00000165 | cg00000236 | admin.disease_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A | 0.461440642939772 | 0.143910373119058 | 0.847164847154162 | kirp |
| TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A | 0.595894468074615 | 0.0807243779293262 | 0.867305510246114 | kirp |
| TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A | TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01A | 0.437447195378987 | 0.898927359292032 | kirp |

Comment: can you please add a simple mock up example with less number of rows and show how the input and output should be ?

Comment: Still the inputs are unclear. Can you please a simple table for your input ? you have specified that the index should match `If the index values match` - but from the values which you have shared the index are not matching

Comment: for inputs, just form tables with sample input and create a corresponding output.